# Outcome of one event from two independent events

Tags: probability, statistics

If there are two independent events with two outcomes, and let's say one outcome has the probability of $A$%, is the probability of the union of the outcome (with the known probability) and one outcome of the other event also $A$%? Or less? Or greater? Or in proportion to the % of the unknown outcome?

Here's an example:
There's a kindergarten with graduation rate $92$%. The gender and the graduation rate are independent. What is the graduation rate of female students graduating?

Please help. I think it's $92$%, but I'm not so sure. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I think you're right. If the gender and graduation rate are independent, that means that the graduation of female students is the same as the graduation rate of the male students. So both would be 92%

> "Two events are independent if the occurrence of one does not change
>   the probability of the other occurring. "

https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m170/ch05-rul.html